# C# simulated polymorphism of static classes?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have been thinking the design over for a couple days now and I'm asymptotically 100% sure this is a design problem. However, here's my predicament: I essentially want to have a compiler checked and polymorphic static classes. Specifically, I have this:

```
static class TileSettings
{
    static class TileOne
    {
        public const TileType TYPE = TileType.TileOne;
    }

    static class TileTwo
    {
        public const TileType TYPE = TileType.TileTwo;
    }
}
```

This seems fine but I would like to have the subclasses to follow a contract (like an interface) that `TileOne` and `TileTwo` could follow so that somewhere in code I could do something like the following:

```
public void function(TileSettings SETTINGS_TO_USE)
{
    someLocalVariable = SETTINGS_TO_USE.TYPE;
}

function(TileOne);
function(TileTwo);
```

One major problem that sticks out to me though is that one can't pass a static class into a function. What I could do is have a static class with methods that take a TileType and use a switch to return that types value. That seems like it would be highly inefficient, however, if it ends up being called a lot. So, any thoughts? Is there something simple I'm unaware of that would solve this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). OOP is based on objects, not static classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer is: don't use a static class.

How about this:

```
class TileSettings
{
    public readonly TileType TYPE;

    public static readonly TileSettings TileOne = new TileSettings(TileType.TileOne);
    public static readonly TileSettings TileTwo = new TileSettings(TileType.TileTwo);

    public TileSettings(TileType type)
    {
         TYPE = type;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this then:

```
public void function(TileSettings settings)
{
    someLocalVariable = settings;
}

function(TileSettings.TileOne);
function(TileSettings.TileTwo);
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid the Singleton pattern from readings but this is quite elegant and works nicely. One change I made was to make `TileOne` and `TileTWo` readonly so they don't accidentally get changed. Is there any reason I shouldn't though?
EDIT- By changed I mean `public readonly static`

Comment: It's actually something you really should do if you are going down that route. I adjusted the code.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to stop using static classes if you desire polymorphism.  Your initial hunch that this is a design problem sounds accurate to me.  There is no good way to achieve this without some sort of hack that would no doubt be problematic from a maintenance/usability/readability standpoint.

Maybe you need something more like a singleton; you would still have instances underneath but generally refer to only one specific instance.

Comment: Like I mentioned on the ChrisWue's comment I wanted to avoid the Singleton. But if it's just not feasible with static classes the singleton works pretty well. I suppose I'll throw some caution to the wind. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's true that singleton is more of an "anti-pattern" ( http://accu.org/index.php/journals/337 ) so it's good to not rely on it all that much.  However, it is a superior solution compared to pure static classes.